# First Posts queues are frustrating to work through

Tags: discussion

The 2 main issues with the First Post queue is that it is difficult to do what you need to do, and the controls we do have are unclear and don't appear to actually have much merit much of the time.

If a question is just off topic, wrong for SU, spam, or any other thing which many of our first questions are, I have to click out of the queue and find the controls I NEED to use on the question or answer itself rather than their being where they used to be, right where they were most useful.

Comment: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/369013/review-queue-workflows-final-release/369017#comment1231489_369017